# How to tidy up a messy echo statement

Tags: php, html, css

Hi guys im still relatively new to web design, and frustrated by only being able to pass my information i get from PHP, whilst in PHP - which forces me to use the echo statement. This in turn gets a bit messy as below:

```
echo  '<div class="jokes"> <p>' . $joke1[$x] . '</p><p class="meta"> uploader ' . $uploader[$x] . ' date: ' . $joke_date[$x] .' <p/> </div>' ;
```

What i would like is to have the word uploader in the meta tag in one color, and the PHP passed variable $uploader[$x] in another color. By adding more style tags i am getting a bit confused about keeping track of the points and quotes. Any suggestions?

Many thanks

Comment: replace all dots with comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give you a start:

```
<style>

 .blue { color: blue;}
 .red { color: red;}
</style>


<?php
echo  '<div class="jokes"> <p>' . $joke1[$x] . '</p><p class="meta"> <span class="blue">uploader</span> <span class="red">' . $uploader[$x] . '</span> date: ' . $joke_date[$x] .' <p/> </div>' ;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
echo  '<div class="jokes"> <p>' . $joke1[$x] . '</p><p class="meta"> <span class="color-1">uploader </span><span class="color-2">' . $uploader[$x] . '</span> date: ' . $joke_date[$x] .' <p/> </div>' ;
```

And you can assign any color to the color-1 and color-2 class.